# The use of being in a sentence to say something that has just happened

Tags: sentence-construction, usage

Which one of these is correct to say about a payment that is just entered in the system (few minutes ago) for payment:

1. These are being entered in the system for payment.
2. These are being entered now in the system for payment.
3. These are entered in the system for payment.
4. These have been entered in the system for payment.

Comment: _Are being entered_ means that it is happening  _now_. If the transaction is finished, use (4).

Comment: Why would any of them be wrong? You tell us, please.

Answer (score 0):

Q. **Which one of these is correct to say about a payment that is just entered in the system (few minutes ago) for payment:**

---

These are being entered in the system for payment.

These are being entered now in the system for payment.

These are entered in the system for payment.

These have been entered in the system for payment.

---

Again a no context phrase. These type of question are so difficult to answer.

Firstly I would suggest **entered into** would be the correct phrase

Secondly what is "for payment"?

Does it form part of a name "system for payment". or a phrase? What does it mean?

Or should it be **entered in the system "ready" for payment**

Finally **what are you trying to say**. As Kate has correctly pointed out your statements have different meanings.

---

1. These are being entered in the **"System for Payment"**. (entered into a type of Payment system)

---

2.These are being entered now (at this minute) **into** the system **ready** for payment.

---

3.These are entered into the system for payment. (describing an action) We take the Cheques **these are entered into the system for payment** into the client accounts.

---

4. These have been entered in the system for payment. (describing an action in the past) Where are the Cheques? I  **entered them into the system for payment** to the client accounts. Then I filed them

---

Example [**How To Get Your Salary Paid Into Your Account**](https://www.hsbc.co.uk/current-accounts/how-to-get-salary-paid-into-account/)  Ref HSBC

Answer (score 0):

1. and 2) mean the same; the 'now' in 2) is redundant.

(3) does not tell the time of the event.  Such a construction can be used to describe any event that is always true.

(4) says that the event has occurred, as you have intended.

Comment: You know we generally say: A construction like that or such as that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: (**4**)

All the sentences are in passive voice.

The first two sentences are in the present continuous/progressive tense. (These *are **being***...payment) The action is not finished. It is continuing.

The third sentence is in the simple present tense. We can say 'These are...payment every Monday/once a week/every day/every month etc.'

The last one is in the present perfect tense. (These **have been**...payment) The action is finished. This is the correct answer.

The simple past tense can also be used if time (yesterday, last week, a few minutes etc.) is mentioned. These *were*...payment a few minutes ago.